# Typed Category Theory?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

[This](http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~fokkinga/mmf92b.pdf) small book (or long paper) describes objects and morphisims in a cateogry as having types. He also talks about pre-categories as categories with typeless objects and morphisims.

While I am totally in favor of forcing types on objects, is this standard? Can objections arise from a certain field when taken this approach?

Comment: This is not standard. The standard way I know to relate category theory and type theory is to think of a category itself as a type system.

Comment: I prefer more this way since its more computational, but then I get a little confused when the objects are sets.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that in category theory is standard to reguard the morphisms as having a specified source and a specified target, so morphisms should always be *typed* in your sense.

Beside that I would rather avoid to call those things pre-categories, mainly because in category theory that term is already used to denote other things.

Using of untyped morphisms is usually strongly discouraged because is could rise complexity in formal proof.